# External HTML file in Bootstrap Popover content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

When I use iframe to load external html file in popover content, it is restricting to popup height. But I want popup height to be auto. Some one help me out .!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pop-right').popover({ 
title : 'Loading External File',
html : true,
placement : "right",
content: function () {
      return '<iframe src="popover-content.html" style="border:none"></iframe>';    
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are not cross-domaining', i.e. you are not loading google.com or similar into the iframe, it is relatively easy.

Declare the below function, which takes the popover element (`.pop-right`) and the popover content `<iframe>` as parameters :

```
function adjustPopover(popover, iframe) {
    var height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px',
        popoverContent = $(popover).next('.popover-content');
    iframe.style.height = height;
    popoverContent.css('height', height);
}
```

1) get `scrollHeight` of the iframe (the real height)
2) get the `.popover-content` `<div>` associated with `.pop-right`
3) set `.popover-content` to the real height, and do the same with the `<iframe>` to avoid scrollbars.

Then, in your popover initialisation call `adjustPopover()` in the iframes onload-event with `onload="adjustPopover(&quot;.pop-right&quot;, this);"` :

```
$('.pop-right').popover({ 
   title : 'Loading External File',
   html : true,
   placement : "right",
   content: function() {
       return '<iframe src="content.html" style="border:none" onload="adjustPopover(&quot;.pop-right&quot;, this);"></iframe>';    
   }
});
```

It is a good idea to set a minimum height for the iframes. If you dont do that, popovers will always have at least the browsers default height of an iframe, in chrome 150px.

```css
iframe {
    height: 40px;
    min-height : 40px;
}
```

Here is an jsfiddle example loading the jsfiddle file */css/normalize.css* -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ovky3796/**

As you see, I also changes `.popover` `max-width` in the demo. This is for demonstration only, if you want to adjust the width of the popover according to the content of the `<iframe>`, do the same as above with `scrollWidth` instead.